# What is the different between <class> with <class> and <class> with <mixin>

Tags: dart

What is the different between `<class> with <class>` and `<class> with <mixin>` ?

I have a example:

```
class Run {
  void run(String name) {
    print('$name run');
  }
}

class People with Run {}

class Dog with Run {}

void main() {
  final people = People();
  final dog = Dog();
  people.run('${people.runtimeType}');
  dog.run('${dog.runtimeType}');
}
```

I cannot seen different after i had changed `class Run` to `mixin Run`

Answer (score 0):

`mixin` is used to specify that the class is only to be used as a mixin.

You can mixin plain classes or abstract classes, but they can be subclassed and the former can be instanced. If you want to prevent that you should use a mixin. I believe it should be more common to define `mixins` purposefully.

`mixin` rules are different from mixing in other classes.

Read more about [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.1/super-mixins/feature-specification.md#dart-2-mixin-declarations).